# Calculating $C$ in $I_{CM} = CMR^2$

Tags: rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I am a bit new here, so please excuse any errors I might make.

I am a student in an AP Physics C: Mechanics course and I am conducting an experiment where I am experimentally calculating the C values of 6 spheres.

$C$ is defined by the equation $I_{CM} = CMR^2$, where $I_{CM}$ is the moment of inertia about the center of a sphere, $M$ is the mass of the sphere and $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

Each sphere is identical, the only differences between them being the material they are made out of and the mass of each sphere. While I know the C value for a rolling sphere is $\frac{2}{5}$, the values I calculated are very, very high and sporadic. I'll lead you through my process of calculating the C value for each ball and then bring up some possible reasons of why I my experimental values are wrong. Any input and correction would be appreciated, I'm completely stuck right now.

Because the balls are rolling down a ramp, I set up an equation such that $E_{total} = E_{translational} + E_{rotational}$.

Assuming friction and air resistance are negligible, I get $gmh = \frac{mv^2}{2} + \ \frac{I\omega^2}{2}$

Knowing the equation for rotational inertia and angular frequency and setting up the equation to solve for C, I get $C = \frac{2gh-v^2}{v^2}$

However, when plugging in all of my data I took, I get C values that are A, very inconsistent, and B, way too high (ranging from 1.64071 to 2.46708). I know that the true C values of the spheres are $\frac{2}{5}$, but I am struggling to pinpoint why the C values are impossibly high and why they differ for each ball. I have two ideas for why my calculated C values are incorrect:

1. Because I am not accounting for the energy lost from point A to point B as the ball rolls down the ramp, my final velocities I calculated are weighted too high for the C values to be correct.
2. Because the balls are slipping while rolling, the velocity value from $\omega = \frac{v}{r}$ is not always same as the translational velocity of the ball moving down the ramp as I assumed in my equation.

If any further explanations are needed, I can provide them, though I should note that my knowledge of physics is very limited, so I will try my best.

Comment: What is $x$?  How does it enter into the equation for energy conservation?

Comment: Also, you should be aware that "the $C$ value" for a rolling object is not a universally known name for this concept.  I *assume* from context that it's defined by $I_{CM} = C M R^2$, where $R$ is the radius of the object;  but you should [edit] your question to make this explicit.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The X was a typo, I meant to but V there instead of X. Thanks for pointing that out.

As for the my use of "the C value" for a rolling object, I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're saying. What I was trying to convey was that from my knowledge, the C value of a solid sphere can be either $\frac{3}{5}$ or $\frac{2}{5}$ depending on the axis of rotation. In this case, the C value should be $\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: *"As for the my use of "the C value" for a rolling object, I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're saying."* He's saying that no one is going to know what you mean when you write "the C value." Because no one outside of your class uses that term. You have that term in the title of your question so you are starting off on the wrong foot.

Comment: (You can edit your question, including the title of the question... and you should do so to make your question more clear, or it could be closed for lack of clarity.)

Comment: To add to Michael and hft's comments -- if you were to add a sentence near the beginning of your question saying, "$C$ is defined by the equation $I_{CM}=CMR^2$, where $I_{CM}$ is the moment of inertia about the center of mass of the sphere, $M$ is the mass of the sphere, and $R$ is the radius of the sphere," then I think they would be satisfied. They are saying you haven't given a conceptual definition of what $C$ is, and not many people call that quantity $C$. In more general terms, whenever you use mathematical notation, you should define it (even if you think it's standard).

Comment: I see, I updated the title and included the equation for the moment of inertia of a spherical object with some mass. I hope this adds clarity to my question, but I can change it further if needed.

Comment: For #1 -- you should be able to check explicitly whether this is a good assumption or not by plotting $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$ as a function of time for your measured value of $C$ and seeing if it is approximately constant, and equal to $mgh$.

Comment: Thanks for the input Andrew, I understand what the others were trying to tell me, I apologize about the confusion. I will update the post with your explanation.

Comment: With C equal 2/5 the final velocity is $~V_{f}=\sqrt{\dfrac{10}{7}gh}~$ is this the case ? If not the rolling condition is not fulfilled.